# Reihenfolge der Wörter in diesem Satz

Tags: sentence-structure

there is that excercise in my learning book, gives you words and you must form a sentence, the words are:
Nach - Mittagessen - mit - Kunden - ich - telefonieren müssen

Answers:

1. Nach dem Mittagessen muss ich mit Kunden telefonieren.
2. Nach dem Mittagessen mit Kunden muss ich telefonieren.

the first one is grammatically accurate that's for sure, but is the second correct? and if so, do both answers give the same meaning?

Comment: Also possible, but unclear: Ich muss nach dem Mittagessen mit Kunden telefonieren. This can just be "heard" but not "read". Interpretation 1: Ich muss (nach dem Mittagessen mit Kunden) telefonieren. Interpretation 2: Ich muss nach dem Mittagessen (mit Kunden telefonieren).

Answer (score 11):

Both are possible, but they do not have the same meaning.

The first one:

> Nach dem Mittagessen muss ich mit Kunden telefonieren.

means:

> After lunch, I must make a phone call with customers.

whereas:

> Nach dem Mittagessen mit Kunden muss ich telefonieren.

means:

> After lunch with customers, I must make a phone call.

So this is quite similar to how this "works" in English.

Comment: I think it would be more accurate, if you set the comma.

Comment: @watchme: what comma?

Comment: hasn't the comma to be set after "Mittagessen" because the first part is a "Gliedsatz" and the next a "Hauptsatz"?

Comment: @watchme: No, not as far as I know.

Comment: Also possible, but unclear: Ich muss nach dem Mittagessen mit Kunden telefonieren. This can just be "heard" but not "read". Interpretation 1: Ich muss (nach dem Mittagessen mit Kunden) telefonieren. Interpretation 2: Ich muss nach dem Mittagessen (mit Kunden telefonieren).